# WPF Polygon Intersection

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, geometry, polygon

What is the best method to check if two **concave** polygons overlap?

```
bool IsIntersection(Polygon poly1, Polygon poly2) {
    // return true / false
}
```

Comment: http://collisiondetection2d.net/ has a free ebook with some useful advice

Comment: maybe, but it's not free

Comment: I also read somewhere about projecting each pair of faces onto the x-axis, and checking for overlaps there. EDIT: here: gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169

Comment: my polygon it's not convex so I can't use that theorem

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution here. It's based on segment intersection.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/